# Adding label to a vector in a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've found this post here:
[graph of pendulum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305028/graph-of-pendulum)
and the nice answer of user @Torbjørn T.
I cannot figure out how to name the tension of the spring (blue vector).
I guess it will be below the line: `\draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$);` but I don't know instruction to give. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % save length of g-vector and theta to macros
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gvec}{1.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}
    % calculate lengths of vector components
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gcos}{\Gvec*cos(\myAngle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gsin}{\Gvec*sin(\myAngle)}

    \coordinate (centro) at (0,0);
    \draw[dashed,gray,-] (centro) -- ++ (0,-3.5) node (mary) [black,below]{$ $};
    \draw[thick] (centro) -- ++(270+\myAngle:3) coordinate (bob);
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--centro--bob};
    \draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$);
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!-\Gcos cm!(centro)$)
      coordinate (gcos)
      node[midway,above right] {$a\cos\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gsin cm!90:(centro)$)
      coordinate (gsin)
      node[midway,above left] {$a\sin\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ++(0,-\Gvec)
      coordinate (g)
      node[near end,left] {$g$};
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = g--bob--gcos};
    \filldraw [fill=black!40,draw=black] (bob) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have look --- pos=0.5 means midway of the vector -- adjust to taste -- the remains are self-explanatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$)node[right,pos=0.5, color=black, font=\scriptsize](){$a$};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate the help. In order to be sure that I understand how could one include the length of the string (next to the vertical dashed line for instance midway to it)?

Comment: may I suggest a separate question for a larger audience

Comment: Thanks again for your quick feedback. If I understood correctly, do you suggest me to post another question?

Comment: you understand correct