# Adding delimiting arrows to a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sequel to question: [Adding label to a vector in a tikz figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568672/adding-label-to-a-vector-in-a-tikz-figure)

Following the answer of user @js bibra I get the desired result

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % save length of g-vector and theta to macros
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gvec}{1.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}
    % calculate lengths of vector components
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gcos}{\Gvec*cos(\myAngle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gsin}{\Gvec*sin(\myAngle)}

    \coordinate (centro) at (0,0);
    \draw[dashed,gray,-] (centro) -- ++ (0,-3.5) node (mary) [black,below]{$ $};
    \draw[thick] (centro) -- ++(270+\myAngle:3) coordinate (bob);
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--centro--bob};
    \draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$);
\draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$)node[right,pos=0.5, color=black](){$T$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!-\Gcos cm!(centro)$)
      coordinate (gcos)
      node[midway,above right] {$a\cos\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gsin cm!90:(centro)$)
      coordinate (gsin)
      node[midway,above left] {$a\sin\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ++(0,-\Gvec)
      coordinate (g)
      node[near end,left] {$g$};
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = g--bob--gcos};
    \filldraw [fill=black!40,draw=black] (bob) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I want know is to include two arrows delimiting the length of the string L as in the following picture.[image] (Ignore the other details of the picture).
Thanks again for any help!

Comment: please have a look -- if color to be change edit red to black in the line --   `\tkzDrawSegment[style=black, dashed, dim={$L$,-15pt,midway,font=\scriptsize, rotate=90}](centro,mary)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % save length of g-vector and theta to macros
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gvec}{1.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}
        % calculate lengths of vector components
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gcos}{\Gvec*cos(\myAngle)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gsin}{\Gvec*sin(\myAngle)}
        
        \coordinate (centro) at (0,0);
        \draw[dashed,gray,-] (centro) -- ++ (0,-3.5) node (mary) [black,below]{$ $} ;
        
%       \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$g$,-20pt,above=0pt,font=\tiny}](centro,mary)
        \tkzDrawSegment[style=red, dashed, dim={$L$,-15pt,midway,font=\scriptsize, rotate=90}](centro,mary)
        \draw[thick] (centro) -- ++(270+\myAngle:3) coordinate (bob);
        \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--centro--bob};
        \draw [blue,-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$)node[right,, color=black, font=\scriptsize](){$a$};
        \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!-\Gcos cm!(centro)$)
        coordinate (gcos)
        node[midway,above right] {$a\cos\theta$};
        \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gsin cm!90:(centro)$)
        coordinate (gsin)
        node[midway,above left] {$a\sin\theta$};
        \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ++(0,-\Gvec)
        coordinate (g)
        node[near end,left] {$g$};
        \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = g--bob--gcos};
        \filldraw [fill=black!40,draw=black] (bob) circle[radius=0.1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```