# How do I add a point that says 'CM' (centre of mass) at the point where the forces of mgcos(theta), mgsin(theta and mg extend, shown by the red point

Tags: tikz-pgf

An image of the diagram is shown, I aim to make it say CM but am not sure how to.

[image]

The code is shown here:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3.2cm}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=1.425]
% save length of g-vector and theta to macros
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Gvec}{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}
% calculate lengths of vector components
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Gcos}{\Gvec*cos(\myAngle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Gsin}{\Gvec*sin(\myAngle)}

\coordinate (centro) at (0,0);
\draw[dashed,gray,-] (centro) -- ++ (0,-3.5) node (mary) [black,below]{$ $};
\draw[thick] (centro) -- ++(270+\myAngle:3) coordinate (bob);
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--centro--bob};
\draw [blue, -stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$);
\draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!-\Gcos cm!(centro)$)
  coordinate (gcos)
  node[midway,above right] {$mg\cos\theta$};
\draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gsin cm!90:(centro)$)
  coordinate (gsin)
  node[midway,above left] {$mg\sin\theta$};
\draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ++(0,-\Gvec)
  coordinate (g)
  node[near end,left] {$mg$};
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = g--bob--gcos};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Free body diagram of physical pendulum (author's own)}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Author's own? It looks a lot to this one to me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305028/graph-of-pendulum/305035#305035

Comment: oh haha, yes in my acknowledgements I cited the source and the user in my references section so don't worry, I understand how that would look without proper context.

Comment: You have asked the same question twice. Please delete one of them. Also acknowledge any answers that you might get..